# Django model with computed column

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.1

How can I represent a column with a default value (specified in SQL) in a django model?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    id SERIAL,
    myGuid VARCHAR DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    anotherColumn VARCHAR
)
```

Model:

```
class myTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #How to represent myGuid column
    anotherColumn = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "myTable"
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.4.2

Comment: This is untested and I could be overlooking something, so I'm not putting it in as an answer.  But I don't see any reason you can't just create your table directly in your database client rather than going through syncdb, then declare a field with `blank=True` on your model so that you can validate without requiring a non-default value for the field.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper would I still be able to access `myGuid` with `blank=True`?  In other words, does `blank=True` make `myGuid` readonly where I can read `myGuid` from the database but wont ever write values I have for `myGuid` to the database?

Comment: No, blank=True just allows things like the admin to validate the model without having a value set in the Python representation for myGuid.  You can still change the myGuid value.  If you want it to be un-editable but still readable, I can't think offhand of a way to get Django to do that universally - maybe denying update access at the database level to the Django user would do that?  You could approximate it through a custom `save` method on the model, but that would be bypassable with a raw SQL query.

Comment: You can't really do this with Django, or rather not with with `./manage.py syncdb`. You might be better setting `managed=False` in `class Meta` and creating the table manually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining it at DB level, you can use uuid from python as default value for the uuid field.

```
import uuid
def get_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

class myTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    myuuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, default=get_uuid)
    anotherColumn = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "myTable"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'd like to define it at the database level for a few reasons.  One simple reason is that I'd like other developers to be able to easily insert into this table without having to remember to use the `uuid_generate_v4` function.

Comment: @steaks, Overhead of handling such field (not managed by django but used) is much more as explained by Peter in comments. You may want to defined a custom model field for this, then you just define the model with that field.